# Laravel Order Collection Through Double Relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, eloquent-relationship

I am sending a `Vehicle` to my blade template which has a relationship of `products` that displays all the products fitting a vehicle.

**Vehicle.php**

```
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'vehicle_product');
}
```

I am strugging to figure out how to order those products based on a 3rd relationship's (`product_group()`) priority attribute.

**Product.php**

```
public function product_group() {
    return $this->belongsTo(ProductGroup::class);
}
```

**Blade Template**

```
@foreach ($vehicle->products->orderBy('product_group.priority') as $product)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortby) instead of `orderBy` but you must have `products` and `product_group` on 'vehicle' before applying it.

```
$vehicle = Post::query()
    ->with([
        'products' => fn($q) => $q->with('product_group') 
    ])
    ->where('id', 1)
    ->first();

$vehicle->products
    ->sortBy(fn($product) => $product->product_group->priority)
    ->values()
    ->all();
```